# delete files from gac by batch file

Tags: batch-file

i tryied to delete registered files and folders from a gac.
with my script:

```
   rem @echo off
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
set OutputFile=log.txt
set ListFile=list.txt

del %OutputFile%
del %ListFile% >> "%OutputFile%"

iisreset >> "%OutputFile%" 

dir /d /s /b  customdllfile* Logging | findstr /vi ".dll" | findstr /vi "Policy.custompolicy"  >> "%ListFile%"

for /f %%a in (%ListFile%) do call :Sub %%a >> "%OutputFile%"
:Sub 
del /f /s /q %1"\*" >> "%OutputFile%"
goto :eof
```

all good, but after delete from a gac the script also delete files from c folder.
what the problem with my script?

Comment: Well, I have no idea what a "gac" is, but I'm going to assume that your problem is related to you using the recursive `/s` flag (although without knowing your directory structure, it's impossible to say).

Comment: the gac is a folder: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET, aa now i understand.. thanks for your opinion!